# How to ensure I am reading the most recent version of state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I may be missing something. I know `setState` is asynchronous in React, but I still seem to have this question.

Imagine following is a handler when user clicks any of the buttons on my app

```
1. ButtonHandler()
2. {
3. if(!this.state.flag)
4. {
5.   alert("flag is false");
6. }
7. this.setState({flag:true});
8. 
9. }
```

- Now imagine user very quickly clicks first one button then second.
- Imagine the first time the handler got called  `this.setState({flag:true})` was executed, but when second time the handler got called, **the change to the state from the previous call has not been reflected yet** -- and `this.state.flag` returned `false`.
- Can such situation occur (even theoretically)?  What are the ways to ensure I am *reading* most up to date state?
- I know `setState(function(prevState, props){..})` gives you access to previous state but what if I want to only read state like on line 3 and not set it?

Comment: you can pass a function to `setState` to ensure it is always called with the latest state.

Answer (score 3):

As you rightly noted, for setting state based on previous state you want to use the function overload.

> I know setState(function(prevState, props){..}) gives you access to previous state

So your example would look like this:

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      flag: !prevState.flag
    };
  });
}
```

> what if I want to only read state like on line 3 and not set it?

Let's get back to thinking **why** you want to do this.

If you want to perform a side effect (e.g. log to console or start an AJAX request) then the right place to do it is the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method. And it also gives you access to the previous state:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
  if (!prevState.flag && this.state.flag) {
    alert('flag has changed from false to true!');
  }
  if (prevState.flag && !this.state.flag) {
    alert('flag has changed from true to false!');
  }    
}
```

This is the intended way to use React state. You let React manage the state and don't worry about *when* it gets set. If you want to set state based on previous state, pass a function to `setState`. If you want to perform side effects based on state changes, compare previous and current state in `componentDidUpdate`.

Of course, as a last resort, you can keep an instance variable independent of the state.

Answer (score 1):

#### React's philosophy

The state and props should indicate things the components need for rendering. React's render being called whenever the state and props change.

#### Side Effects

In your case, you're causing a side effect based on user interaction which requires specific timing. In my opinion, once you step out of rendering - you probably want to reconsider `state` and `props` and stick to a regular instance property which is synchronous anyway.

#### Solving the real issue - Outside of React

Just change `this.state.flag` to `this.flag` everywhere, and update it with assignment rather than with `setState`. That way you

#### If you still *have* to use .state

You can get around this, uglily. I wrote code for this, but I'd rather not publish it here so people don't use it :)

- First [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).
- Then use a utility for only caring about the last promise resolving in a function call. [Here is an example library](https://github.com/domenic/last) but the actual code is ~10LoC and simple anyway.
- Now, a promisified setState with `last` called on it gives you the guarantee you're looking for.

Here is how using such code would look like:

```
 explicitlyNotShown({x: 5}).then(() => {
  // we are guaranteed that this call and any other setState calls are done here. 
 });
```

(Note: with MobX this isn't an issue since state updates are sync).